# Sitecore 8 5 update #5 exception on step4 (MongoDB exception)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to update Sitecore 8 update 4 to update 5, but via UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx I see an error in w3wp (iis) and wizard never done. 
How to fix it ? I don't see any error.

### Update

In the Sitecore log I see an exception related to MongoDB

> ERROR Exception when executing agent processing/taskAgent Exception:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DatabaseNotAvailableException Message:
>   Database not available Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.HandleDatabaseException(ExceptionBehavior
>   exceptionBehavior, Exception ex)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action
>   action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery
>   query, IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, Boolean returnNew,
>   Boolean upsert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.MongoDbTaskStorageProvider.PickFirstExclusiveTask()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskQueue.TryGetNext(Guid
>   taskIdBoundary, ProcessingTask& workItem)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TasksAgent.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException Message: Unable to
>   connect to server localhost:27017: No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017. Source:
>   MongoDB.Driver    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan
>   timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.ChooseServerInstance(ReadPreference
>   readPreference)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.AcquireConnection(ReadPreference
>   readPreference)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand
>   command, IBsonSerializer resultSerializer, IBsonSerializationOptions
>   resultSerializationOptions)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand
>   command)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery query,
>   IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, IMongoFields fields, Boolean
>   returnNew, Boolean upsert)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery query,
>   IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, Boolean returnNew, Boolean
>   upsert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2c.b__2b()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action
>   action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Message: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:27017 Source: System    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer,
>   Int32 requestId)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage
>   message)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection
>   connection)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Ping(MongoConnection connection)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan
>   timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)

I don't use any MongoDb, but I use SOLR in a project.

Comment: Have you checked the Sitecore logs to see what is recorded in there?

Comment: I have added error to body.

Comment: Have you checked the installation history logs? (/temp/__UpgradeHistory) Can you post the errors you see there?

Comment: I can't find /temp/__UpgradeHistory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error it looks like you need to have a valid MongoDB service running. See this SO Question:

[Mongodb: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061)

and

[problem with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721660/problem-with-mongodb)

If you are not running the xDB have you made sure it is disabled according to this guide? https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641

Answer (score 0):

As per the upgrade guide you should be disabling analytics while upgrading.
Please disable Analytics first and then try to apply the update.